# spark add_month doesn't work as expected

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

in a dataframe, I'm generating a column based on column A in DateType format "yyyy-MM-dd". Column A is generated from a UDF (udf generates a random date from the last 24 months).

from that generated date I try to calculate column B. Column B is column A minus 6 months. ex. 2017-06-01 in A is 2017-01-01 in B. 
To achieve this I use function add_months(columname, -6)

when I do this using another column (not generated by udf) I get the right result. But when I do it on that generated column I get random values, totally wrong.

I checked the schema, column is from DateType

this is my code :

```
val test = df.withColumn("A", to_date(callUDF("randomUDF")))
val test2 = test.select(col("*"), add_months(col("A"), -6).as("B"))
```

code of my UDF :

```
sqlContext.udf.register("randomUDF", () => {

//prepare dateformat
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

//get today's date as reference 
val today = Calendar.getInstance()
val now = today.getTime()

//set "from" 2 years from now
val from = Calendar.getInstance()
from.setTime(now)
from.add(Calendar.MONTH, -24)

// set dates into Long
val valuefrom = from.getTimeInMillis()
val valueto = today.getTimeInMillis()

//generate random Long between from and to
val value3 = (valuefrom + Math.random()*(valueto - valuefrom))

// set generated value to Calendar and format date
val calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar3.setTimeInMillis(value3.toLong)
formatter.format(calendar3.getTime()
}
```

UDF works as expected, but I think there is something going wrong here.
I tried the add_months function on another column (not generated) and it worked fine.

example of results I get with this code :

```
A            |      B
2017-10-20   |   2016-02-27
2016-05-06   |   2015-05-25
2016-01-09   |   2016-03-14
2016-01-04   |   2017-04-26
```

using spark version 1.5.1
using scala 2.10.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation of `test2` `dataframe` in your code

```
val test2 = test.select(col("*"), add_months(col("A"), -6).as("B"))
```

is treated by `spark` as

```
val test2 = df.withColumn("A", to_date(callUDF("randomUDF"))).select(col("*"), add_months(to_date(callUDF("randomUDF")), -6).as("B"))
```

So you can see that `udf` function is called twice. `df.withColumn("A", to_date(callUDF("randomUDF")))` is generating the date that comes in `column A`. And `add_months(to_date(callUDF("randomUDF")), -6).as("B")` is calling `udf` function again and generating a new date and subtracting 6 months from it and showing that date in `column B`.

Thats the reason you are getting random dates.

The solution to this would be to use `persist` or `cache` in `test` `dataframe` as

```
val test = df.withColumn("A", callUDF("randomUDF")).cache()
val test2 = test.as("table").withColumn("B", add_months($"table.A", -6))
```